# Error publishing messages to Kafka running inside docker container on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I am using spotify/kafka image for running kafka in docker container on ec2.

I started kafka using the below command:

```
docker run --name kafka -i -t -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST=kafka  -h kafka --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 spotify/kafka
```

It works fine to post and consume the message inside the docker container but doesn't work when i post a message from another ec2 instance.

here is the command i used to post a message to the topic:

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list docker_host_ip:9092 --topic test-topic
```

Here is the error message:

```
[2018-04-19 22:14:30,231] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {test-topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Anyone published the messages remotely on kakfa topic running inside the container?

Comment: Yes, I have, and it works fine assuming the VPC is configured correctly (you also should create the topic first before producing to it)

Comment: I could create topic remotely but encountering LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE while publishing messages to the topic from a different ec2 instance. Did you use public ip address of the ec2 instance for advertised host? did you make any entries in /etc/hosts file?

Comment: Using the private IP within the subnet should work. There is no need to use a public IP unless you are outside of the VPC

Comment: EC2 Instance 1
docker run --detach --name kafka -it -p 2181:2181 -p 9092:9092 --env ADVERTISED_HOST='10.0.0.9' -h '10.0.0.9' --env ADVERTISED_PORT=9092 f9234324fd

server.properties
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.9:9092

EC2 Instance 2
root@ip-10-0-0-89 bin]# ./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 10.0.0.9:9092 --topic test002 --from-beginning

while consuming the messages from remote EC2 instance (part of the same subnet), I get the below error:
Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: 1) The Confluent containers are more up to date than Spotifys 2) Confluent has a docker quickstart guide. 3) I would suggest you actually use `kafka-topics --list` with the zookeeper address before trying to produce or consume. 4) Must you use AWS to test two instances? Can you not use two local Vagrant virtual machines?

Comment: kafka-topics --list  works with public ip address but publish and consume fails.